# How do I revoke access to Twitter logged in from another site?

Tags: twitter, login, oauth

When using Twitter to log in to a site it wants to give that site certain abilities.

How may that be taken back if it's regretted?

I've already unfollowed some people that I didn't follow myself (maybe I'm just forgetful) and I want to take back the abilities from anyone who got them.

[image: Authorisation example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your profile and settings on the Twitter website, select "Apps" from the list on the left, pick the app you don't want and select "Revoke Access".